# How to user sketch app sources templates on android studio?

Tags: android-studio, sketchapp

I'm looking for a way to use sketchappsources.com templates on android studio, I found out that the sketch official application is working only on MAC OS and there is an alternative called Lunacy (by Icon8) that works on windows, the problem is that even after importing the downloaded theme on lunacy I have no idea how am I supposed to get the xml/drawables that I can import into android studio, any one can help please?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use some plugins which are created exactly for this purpose.

For example [Sympli](http://sympli.io) would let you to drag and drop your design into Swift or Android Studio in no time.

There is also some basic tutorial on their website for getting on board.